# items fail to be processed in Akka streams app that uses Source.queues and Sink.queues in a flow

Tags: queue, akka, reactive-streams

I am trying to create an (Akka HTTP) stream procsesing flow using the classes akka.stream.scaladsl.Source and Sink queues.
I am using a queue because I have a processing step in my flow that issues http requests and I want this step to take as many
items off the queue as there are max-open-requests, and stop taking off the queue once max-open-requests are in flight.
The result is that backpressure is applied when my connection pool is overloaded.

Below, I have a very simplified test that reflects the main logic of my app.   In the test 'Stress Spec' (below)
I am simulating a number of simultaneous connections via which I will send a 'Source' of 'Requesto' objects
to the getResponses method of the class ServiceImpl.
In the processing step 'pullOffSinkQueue' you will note that I am incrementing a counter to see how many items
I have pulled off the queue.

The test will send Serviceimpl a set of requests whose cardinality is set to equal 
streamedRequestsPerConnection * numSimultaneousConnections.

When I send 20 requests my test passes fine.  In particular the count of requests pulled off the
Sink.queue  will be equal to the number of requests I send out.   However, if 
I increase the number of requests I send to above 50 or so, I see consistent failures in the test. 
I get a message such as the one below

```
180 was not equal to 200
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.foo.StressSpec at (StressSpec.scala:116)
Expected :200
Actual   :180
<Click to see difference>
```

This indicates that the number of items pulled off the queue does not equal the number of items put on the queue.
I have a feeling this might be due to the fact that my test is not properly  waiting for all items put into the stream
to be processed.    If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be all ears !  Code is below.

```
package com.foo

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import akka.stream.ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy
import akka.stream.{Attributes, Materializer, QueueOfferResult}
import akka.stream.Supervision.resumingDecider
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}


import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, Matchers}

import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future, _}

final case class Responso()
final case class Requesto()

object Handler {
  val dbRequestCounter = new AtomicInteger(0)
}

class Handler(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, mat: Materializer) {
  import Handler._

  private val source =
    Source.queue[(Requesto, String)](8, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  private val sink =
    Sink.queue[(Requesto, String)]().withAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(8, 8))
  private val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue) = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()

  def placeOnSourceQueue(ar: Requesto): Future[QueueOfferResult] = {
    sourceQueue.offer((ar, "foo"))
  }

  def pullOffSinkQueue(qofr: QueueOfferResult): Future[Responso] = {
    dbRequestCounter.incrementAndGet()
    qofr match {
      case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
        sinkQueue.pull().flatMap { maybeRequestPair: Option[(Requesto, String)] =>
          Future.successful(Responso())
        }
      case error =>
        println("enqueuing error: " + error)
        Future.failed(new RuntimeException("enqueuing error: " + error))
    }
  }
}


class ServiceImpl(readHandler: Handler, writeHandler: Handler)
                 (implicit log: LoggingAdapter, mat: Materializer) {
  private val readAttributeFlow: Flow[Requesto, Responso, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[Requesto]
      .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(readHandler.placeOnSourceQueue)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(readHandler.pullOffSinkQueue)
  }

  def getResponses(request: Source[Requesto, NotUsed]): Source[Responso, NotUsed] =
    request
      .via(readAttributeFlow)
      .withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider))

}


class StressSpec
    extends FunSuite
    with MockitoSugar
    with Matchers {

  val streamedRequestsPerConnection  = 10
  val numSimultaneousConnections  = 20

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val log: LoggingAdapter = Logging(actorSystem.eventStream, "test")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  import Handler._

  lazy val requestHandler = new Handler()
  lazy val svc: ServiceImpl =
    new ServiceImpl(requestHandler, requestHandler)

  test("can handle lots of simultaneous read requests") {
    val totalExpected  = streamedRequestsPerConnection * numSimultaneousConnections

    def sendRequestAndAwaitResponse(): Unit = {
      def getResponses(i: Integer) = {
        val requestStream: Source[Requesto, NotUsed] =
          Source(1 to streamedRequestsPerConnection)
            .map { i =>
              Requesto()
            }
        svc.getResponses(requestStream).runWith(Sink.seq)
      }

      val responses: immutable.Seq[Future[immutable.Seq[Responso]]] =
        (1 to numSimultaneousConnections).map { getResponses(_) }
      val flattenedResponses: Future[immutable.Seq[Responso]] =
        Future.sequence(responses).map(_.flatten)
      Await.ready(flattenedResponses, 1000.seconds).value.get
    }

    sendRequestAndAwaitResponse()
    dbRequestCounter.get shouldBe(totalExpected)

  }
}
```